# Rosdep fails and blocks the shell

Tags: rosdep, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have some troubles with rosdep under Osx Lion.
It is not able to find the dependencies I need...some examples are eigen and tinyxml.
In installed both of them through macport (I prefer to use it instead of Homebrew) and I modified my `.profile` in this way:

```
export CPATH=/opt/local/include:/usr/local/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/lib
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/local/lib:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/
```

Furthermore when I execute

```
rosdep -install geometry
```

it blocks my shell and I have to reset it for being able to prompt commands again. Sometimes this problems also leaves a running process, called tclsh8.5 which uses a lot of CPU.

How can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12251/rosdep-fails-and-blocks-the-shell/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this ticket your issue? https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3752

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-12-07**:
@tfoote actually it fixed the problem of the process, but not the one of the dependencies. Thanks!